# Can you kill a enemy in the med bay?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Sometimes, when fighting a enemy while boarding, they retreat to the medbay to heal themselves. It is worth going after them to finish them off? Consider 1v1 in a level 1 Medbay.

I'm not asking possible ways to kill people on the medbay nor possible tactics, but if the melee attack damage can overcome the healing of a level 1 Medbay, and under which circumstances.

Comment: That's very circumstantial. I'd say yes but don't have the time to write up a good answer right now.

Comment: a mantis definitely can do it in a level 1 medbay, I've done it before but its very painful to try and I had to use heal bursts a few times.

Comment: If the enemy is retreating to the medbay to heal, it's likely they are very low health, and even a single laser would be enough to outright kill them whilst they're in the medbay. If it doesn't, well at least they won't be healing :)

Comment: @Robotnik I know, but that's not my question (no offense). I want to know if, given the situation, a melee combat can overcome the healing

Comment: I have some gut feelings on it (from my gameplay), but I'm having trouble finding any hard numbers to back them up. Anyone have a link to the raw data? (Mantis get 1.5x damage, but 1.5x of *what*?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**YES.**

It is possible but not under all circumstances.

with following "tactics" you can succeed:

- using racial bonus (e.g. mantis vs. zoltan).
- outmanning them.
- you need to have good melee skills.

anyway, success depends on their level of the medbay.

Considering a 1vs1 in a lvl1 medbay, a trained mantis should already suffice.

I have already done this, sometimes I also finish them with my ships weapons, just aiming on their medbay. Even if the volley would not disable the medbay, each shot does damage to all personnel in the room.
Setting the medbay on fire is a good tactic, too.

Comment: I'm not asking how to kill people on the medbay and possible tactics, but if the melee attack damage can overcome the healing, and under which circumstances. Would a Mantis without training kill someone?

Comment: @SysDragon and i said yes, under circumstances. i cannot say this for sure at the moment, an untrained mantis might not suffice while a rank 1 ("green") mantis could. I can test this later on, but not right now. The tactics are just a + as the question is too broad for a "yes" or a "no"

Comment: You mean "It is possible, but not under *all* circumstances", right?

Comment: I just want to notice that when you say "e.g. mantis vs zoltan", the race of the enemy doesn't change anything

Comment: Actually, the race of the enemy DOES enter into the equation... some have less health, some do less damage than others. Assuming you are doing more damage to them than the med-bay is healing, the more health the enemy has, and the more they're dealing to you, the less likely you'll survive long enough to kill them.

Comment: @aslum exactly!

Comment: @aslum My question is about damage overcoming the healing, not judging if is better situation to attack or not. And damage done to enemies is the same on all races. A zoltan with 10 life and a Rockman with 10 life is the same into the equation

Comment: Then the answer is YES. There are circumstances where you can deal more damage than is healed. However if you are dealing 6HP a second, and they are healing 5HP a second you have to weight if that 1HP/Second of damage will kill them before they kill you.

You asked if it was WORTH it. And that depends on the circumstances.

Comment: I usually consider level 1 medbay healing equal to an untrained human's damage - so any mantis should be able to pull it off.  You could run into a higher-level medbay, though (a level 2 medbay would cancel the damage of 2 untrained Mantis, a level 3 medbay can't be overcome in melee).